# Docker compose - save configuration

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, dockerhub

Here's my docker-compose.yml file, adapted from [here](https://blog.wodby.com/6-reasons-to-deploy-drupal-8-with-docker-how-to-guide-b2f073e61672):

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal8
       MYSQL_USER: drupal8
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal8
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    restart: always

  drupal:
    image: drupal:8.2-apache
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/modules
      - /var/www/html/profiles
      - /var/www/html/themes
      # this takes advantage of the feature in Docker that a new anonymous
      # volume (which is what we're creating here) will be initialized with the
      # existing content of the image at the same location
      - /var/www/html/sites
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql
```

Now on running this and opening up `localhost:8080` in my browser, I'm presented with Drupal's configuration setup, which I duly follow and presto, my first Drupal page is created. What I ultimately need to do is:

1. Save the configuration somehow, so that the settings persist
2. Be able to push these two containers to a single repository in Docker Hub

The end goal is to be able to issue `docker run myDockerHubUsername/myRepo`, which would pull these two containers and Drupal would be preconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose is already saving all the data/configurations you made. Even you destroy the containers, the data persists.

You need to keep your mounted volumes!

If you want to run these somewhere else. You need to always carry your data/volume. Remember to check or change the paths.

For 2nd, it is not advisable to keep multiple images in one image. If you still want. You need to prepare a Dockerfile, and prepare a single image out of that.

Comment: Thanks Gorav - but my question is - when I first spin up the Drupal container, I'm taken to the config page where I enter the required config details and save the site. Ideally I'd like to push this image to Hub along with this configuration so that subsequent pulls of the image won't require the configuration step to be redone - does that make sense?

Comment: Well, I use following aproach, and my configs kept saved always. I do not need to put anything each time.
See https://github.com/GyanBlog/drupal7_DevEnv_mysql